# APNS on Godaddy unable to connect

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I have a godaddy dedicated server on which I have installed SSL certificate from godaddy.

I am using following script for sending push notification

```
$passphrase = 'pass';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '../folder/file/ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)

    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);


//echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' => 1,
    'category' => 'NOTIFICATION'
    );

$payload = json_encode($body);

$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;


fclose($fp);
```

When I run this code from the browser I receive notification but when i run this same code from cron job it gives me unable to connect error.

I ran the script from terminal it gives me the following error

```
stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
```

Comment: Hi @Tushar did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Check if the correct port is open -

http://www.canyouseeme.org. (You are looking for port 2195)

If it is not open then you need to call GoDaddy and ask them to open port 2195 on your dedicated server. (They will not open the port for shared hosting)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips that should can help you out:

1. Go to [entrust.net/downloads/root_request.cfm](https://www.entrust.com/get-support/ssl-certificate-support/root-certificate-downloads/) and download entrust_2048_ca.cer
2. Add following code:
   stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
3. Make sure if path is right: '../folder/file/ck.pem' ?
4. Switch and try both the sandbox and live ssl links.